# An Abelian Type Theorem for Meromorphic Functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

Suppose
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$$
extends meromorphically to the whole complex plane. Show that if
$$\frac{r^n a_n}{n^k}\to c\neq 0\quad \mathrm{as}\quad n\to\infty\quad$$
for some integer $k\geq 0$ and some $r>0$, then $f(z)$ has a pole of order $k+1$ at $z=r$.

I tried finding $\lim_{z\to r}(z-r)f(z)$ but didn't succeed. I also tried to use the root test for $(z-r)f(z)$ but there isn't enough information. Now I don't know where I should start with. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cauchy's integral formula implies that the Taylor series of $f$ at $z=0$ converges for $|z|<r$ where $r$ is the modulus of the first pole. With $s_1,\ldots,s_K$ the finitely many poles on $|z|=r$ of order $e_1,\ldots,e_k$ we get that the Taylor series of $f-\sum_{k\le K}\sum_{j\le e_k} \frac{c_{k,j}}{(z-s_k)^j}$ converges for $|z|< r+\epsilon$. That is to say $$f(z)=\sum_{n\ge 0} a_n z^n, \qquad a_n = \sum_{k\le K} \sum_{j\le e_k} C_{k,j} n^{j-1} s_k^{-n} + O( (r+\epsilon)^{-n})$$
And $a_n\sim C_{e_1,1} s_1^{-n} n^{e_1-1}$ iff $e_1$ is larger than all the other $e_k$

Comment: As you see we do. The asymptotic is given by the first poles, not by the next ones.

Comment: How does this tell us that we have a pole at $z=r$?

Comment: The asymptotic is given by the first poles. From the asymptotic we know the first poles. From the first poles we know the asymptotic.

Comment: I think I roughly understand what you want to say. But anyways your answer was very helpful to me. Thank you so much!